# Making a video player training software

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently making a software that can be used to playback training packages. The features I want to add are:

1. Ability to read the time of videos
2. Ability to play and pause videos of various codecs (as bundled in Klite Codec Pack)
3. Ability to create a custom playlist file and continue from the last stop/pause of the playlist when opened
4. Generate a report of how the playlist was completed

I know very well how I am going to handle the last two parts but I need help on the first two. The current one simply has to launch the files using an external player on the system, and monitor the launched process for exit... but this is not quite what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) with the [.Net Interface to VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC). It supports lots of codecs out of the box and [seems to be really easy to use](http://spunkyvt.wordpress.com/2008/04/21/vlc-and-c/).

Answer (score 1):

If WPF is an option you can use the [`<MediaElement/>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) for hosting the video in an application. Specifically you can use the [`Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position.aspx) property for getting and setting the current time.

As the `<MediaElement/>` is a wrapper for Windows Media Player, all videos playable in WMP should be playable in the `<MediaElement/>` (after you installed necessary codecs).

Comment: great idea. This would mean that those using it should have .NET Franework 3 installed. Bundling it with my exe to work on XP pcs without .net framework is usually not worth the stress.